# Oracle SQL merge tables without specifying columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have a table `people` with less than 100,000 records and I have taken a backup of this table using the following:

```
create table people_backup as select * from people
```

I add some new records to my `people` table over time, but eventually I want to merge the records from my backup table into `people`. Unfortunately I cannot simply `DROP` my table as my new records will be lost!

So I want to update the records in my `people` table using the records from `people_backup`, based on their primary key `id` and I have found 2 ways to do this:

1. [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) the tables together
2. use some sort of [fancy correlated update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Great! However, both of these methods use `SET` and make me specify what columns I want to update. Unfortunately I am lazy and the structure of `people` may change over time and while my `CTAS` statement doesn't need to be updated, my update/merge script will need changes, which feels like unnecessary work for me.

Is there a way merge entire rows without having to specify columns? I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884822/sql-insert-without-specifying-columns-what-happens) that not specifying columns during an `INSERT` will direct SQL to insert values by order, can the same methodology be applied here, is this safe?

NB: The structure of the table will not change between backups

Comment: You always need to specify which columns will be updated. That's just how it works. You could, however, write a script to write a script - eg. `select 'set tgt.'||column_name||' = src.'||colunn_name||',' from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';` that would at least be able to generate the list of columns for you, so you can copy and paste into your statement

Comment: Given that your table is small, could you simply `delete` anything from the table that exists in the backup and then do an `insert` of everything in the backup?  That's slow and not particularly elegant but it meets your requirements.

Comment: Do you want to replace new data with old?

Comment: @JustinCave if you could post as answer I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your table is small, you could simply

```
DELETE FROM table t
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM backup b
                WHERE t.key = b.key );

INSERT INTO table
  SELECT *
    FROM backup;
```

That is slow and not particularly elegant (particularly if most of the data from the backup hasn't changed) but assuming the columns in the two tables match, it does allow you to not list out the columns.  Personally, I'd much prefer writing out the column names (presumably those don't change all that often) so that I could do an update.